# chromeのテキストボックスに入力した全角英数字をjavascriptでリアルタイムに半角へ変換したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

いくつか参考サイトを探し、
http://qiita.com/yoya_k/items/4bce6201fde9ee3a9561

こちらを参考にさせていただきながら、なんとか近い形にはできたのですが
気になったのはそもそも情報が少ないということは、別の方法があるからなのか？
予想ではもっとこの問題で悩んでいる方がいるかと思っておりましたので意外でした。

ime-modeが使えない場合の基本的なやり方が分かればと思います。
入力モードが全角になっていても半角の数値のみが入力（即時変換？）可能にしたいです。
実現可能であれば、jqueryやangularjs等も利用したいと思っています。
何卒どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

リアルタイムで…というのは、IMEの挙動も制御したいということですよね？

その前提で話をしますが。
私が思うに、そもそも情報が少ないのは、そのような制御が好ましくないからです。
(うろ覚えですがime-modeすら廃止の勧告を受けた記憶があります)

例えばあるユーザーは「郵便番号辞書」を使いたくても入力できなくなります。
さらに「あれ？なんで勝手に入力確定しているんだ！？」と大変驚くことでしょう。
ユーザービリティの観点からすべきではありません。
普通に、pattern属性なり$watchなりで入力確定したものを検証すべきです。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
なるほど、確かにime-modeは先々（？）廃止との記事も見かけました。
参考になりました！

Answer (score 0):

onkeydownでキー種を取得してpreventDefaultすればいいです。

Answer (score 0):

参考サイトのやり方ですとFirefoxでは使用できないため  
あまり実用的ではないです。  
http://qiita.com/yoya_k/items/4bce6201fde9ee3a9561